# Is there a Scala equivalent for the python enumerate?

Tags: scala, enumerate

I'd like the convienience of

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(sys.argv[1])):
  print i, line
```

when doing the following in Scala

```
for (line <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines()) {
  println(line)
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use the `zipWithIndex` from Iterable trait:

```
for ((line, i) <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().zipWithIndex) {
   println(i, line)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think its:

for ((line, i) <- Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines().zipWithIndex)

Comment: I don't know what Python does, but this starts with index 0 and not index 1 for the first line.

Comment: Python does the same. This is standard for indexing of sequences. The method is `zipWithIndex`, not `zipWithLineNumber`

Answer (score 11):

As already answered by others, if you want your index to start from 0, you can use `zipWithIndex`:

```
for ((elem, i) <- collection.zipWithIndex) {
    println(i, elem)
}
```

Because `zipWithIndex` creates a copy of the collection if called on the collection itself, you may want to call it to a `view` of the colleciton instead: `collection.view.zipWithIndex`.

Nonetheless, Python's `enumerate` has an optional parameter to set the start value of your index. In scala, you can do:

```
for ((elem, i) <- collection.zip(Stream from 1) {
    println(i, elem)
}
```

For a longer discussion, read https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-zipwithindex-create-for-loop-counters-scala-cookbook.